# What should frexp(FLT_MAX, ...) return?

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754

What should the output of the following program be?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>

int main() {
    int exp;
    float mant = frexp(FLT_MAX, &exp);
    printf("frexp(%a) = {%f, %d}\n", FLT_MAX, mant, exp);
    return 0;
}
```

On my amd64 Linux system with glibc it prints:

```
frexp(0x1.fffffep+127) = {1.000000, 128}
```

From [the IEEE 754 Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Examples) I see that the "Largest normalized number" has an exponent of 127. I also see that the only values with an exponent of 128 are ±Infinity and NaN.

From [the frexp man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/frexp) I understand that frexp() should return a value in the range [0.5, 1.0) (that is, excluding 1.0).

Both the mantissa and exponent returned seem to be incorrect based on those pieces of information.

Knowing what frexp() does and the value of FLT_MAX (= (2 - 2^-23) * 2^127) tells me that {1.0, 128} is indeed very close to the correct answer, since (2 - 2^-23) is very close to 2.

So what should frexp(FLT_MAX, ...) return?

Comment: `(0.5, 1.0]` should be `[0.5, 1.0)` by the way :)

Comment: This should not be the question of what `frexp()` returns but what precision should be used as you yourself said *Knowing what frexp() does and the value of FLT_MAX (= (2 - 2^-23) * 2^127) tells me that {1.0, 128} is indeed very close to the correct answer, since (2 - 2^-23) is very close to 2* , this means you are losing precision .Try `double` instead of `float` .

Comment: For single precision floats you should use `frexpf` instead of `frexp`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I give you credit for printing `FLT_MAX` out in `%a` format, so you can see what the value actually is, as opposed to what `%f` prints it as. So why not do that for the value of `mant`, too?

```
frexp(0x1.fffffep+127) = {0x1.fffffep-1, 128}
```

That result seems unsurprising to me. (Note that the exponent in the IEEE-754 representation is based on a mantissa in the range `[1.0, 2.0)`, whereas `frexp` generates a mantissa in the range `[0.5, 1.0)`. So the `frexp` maximum exponent is one higher.)

Moral: *Never* confuse what a floating point value *is* with how it *looks*.

Comment: Indeed, you are completely right. I should have printed both floats with %a to see what was really happening.